# Django Invalid credentials while loggin into the account

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying from a few days to create a login & register system for my WebSite, built with Django. But, every time I try to login to my superuser account, or a testaccount that I've created, I get an error. When I enter my credentials in the form and press the Submit button, the page reloads but I am not logged in as a user and no error is given to me. But if I go to the admin page, i'll see an error saying me that Username or Password is invalid. I set this error to make it appear on the login page when the credentials were wrong, but nevertheless, despite the credentials are right, I am given a mistake, and moreover on the wrong page.

Here my code:

File: views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import CreateUserForm


def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)

                return redirect('home')
            

        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Username or password is incorrect')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url="login")
def AccountView(request):
    return render(request, "accounts/account.html")
```

File: login.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/utilities.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>True Bot | Log In your Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <section style="background-color: #fc9842; background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #fc9842 0%, #fe5f75 74%);">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container flex">
                <h1 class="logo">TRUE</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'features' %}">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'docs' %}">Documentation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Head -->
        <section class="features-head bg-primary py-3"
            style="background-color: #fc9842; background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #fc9842 0%, #fe5f75 74%);">
            <div class="container grid">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="xl">Log In</h1>
                    <p class="lead">
                        Log into your True Bot account.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="{% static 'images/login.png' %}" alt="Login Image"
                    style="width: 125px; margin-right: 10rem;">
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="showcase-form card" style="animation: none; display: inline-block;">
            <h2>Login to your <br /><a href="https://truebot.ml" style="color: orangered;">True Bot</a> account</h2>
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-control">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required
                        style="border: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #b4becb; width: 100%;padding: 3px; font-size: 16px;">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

File: forms.py

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change fileldname to username.

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
```

Comment: Also suggest OP to use [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

Comment: For login, use Django forms to get your input and return errors. Using using Django messages will set the error in the admin since that's were the message variable is being loaded and am really sure you don't have the messages variable in any of your templates.